# A question about 0# and truth in levels of the L hierarchy

Tags: set-theory

I'm re-reading a paper of Stevo Todorcevic's entitled "Localized Reflection and Fragments of PFA" and there's a claim in the proof of one of the lemmas that I thought I understood but now I'm not so sure.  The claim is this:

> Suppose $0^{\sharp}$ does not exist, and let $a \in L_{\omega_2}$, $\varphi$ a formula, $\theta$ a regular cardinal in $L$ such that $L_{\theta} \vDash \varphi (a)$.  Then there exists $\lambda$, a cardinal in $V$, such that $\theta \leq \lambda ^+ = (\lambda ^+)^L$ and $L_{\lambda ^+} \vDash \varphi (a)$.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amit, I do not think this is exactly what Stevo is claiming. He writes:

> Let $\varphi$ be a given formula of set theory and suppose that for some 
>   $a\in L_{\omega_2}$ there is $\theta$, a regular cardinal in $L$ such that $L_\theta\models\varphi(a)$. We need to find $\theta'\lt\omega_2$, a regular cardinal in $L$, such that $L_{\theta'}\models\varphi(a)$. Clearly we may assume that $0^\sharp$ does not exist, and therefore (by increasing 
>   $\theta$), that there is a cardinal $\lambda$ in $V$ such that $\theta=\lambda^+=(\lambda^+)^L$.

The point is that he is effectively changing the formula when passing to a larger $\theta$. Say, given $\theta$ and $\varphi$, he finds a (large) singular cardinal $\lambda$ in $V$ whose successor is computed correctly in $L$ (this is the key use of the assumption that $0^\sharp$ does not exist, so we have covering), and notes that $L_{\lambda^+}$ models, say, the statement $\varphi'(a)$ that "the length of the universe is the successor of a cardinal $\lambda$ such that there is a regular cardinal $\theta<\lambda$ such that $L_\theta\models\varphi(a)$." He then proceeds to reflect this statement down, and therefore finds a $\gamma'\lt\omega_2$ regular and successor in $L$ that models $\varphi'(a)$. But then there is a $\theta'\lt\gamma'$ regular in $L$ such that $L_{\theta'}\models\varphi(a)$, and we are done.

Comment: Of course, if $0^\sharp$ exists, then the existence of $\theta'$ is easy: Let $\theta$ be the least $L$-regular such that $L_\theta\models\varphi(a)$. Then $\theta$ is definable from the finite set $A\subset\omega_2$ of indiscernibles that define $a$, and therefore below the first indiscernible larger than the elements of $A$. But this is still below $\omega_2$, since the indiscernibles form an unbounded subset of $\omega_2$.

Comment: Thanks Andres, I didn't realize the formula was changing.  So first off, I don't think we need a large $\lambda$, any singular $\lambda \geq \theta$ should do, no?  Also I don't think you can just hope to reflect down.  Suppose $V=L$, then $\gamma '$ would have to be $\omega _1$, and $\theta '$ would have to be $\omega$, but generally $a \notin L_{\omega}$.  

Comment: @Amit: 1. Yes, that's all I meant by "large $\lambda$": Larger than $\theta$.
2. No, of course not. I meant: Now Stevo runs the argument that is the content of the lemma, and obtains at the end a $\gamma'<\omega_2$ with $L_{\gamma'}$ a model of $\varphi'(a)$. 


Comment: I assume it's more than a matter of mere reflection, otherwise he would have no need for the canonical square sequence he uses in the proof.  The issue is, if $\theta <\gamma$ with $\theta$ regular in $L$ and $\gamma$ successor in $L$, then $L_{\gamma}\vDash \mathrm{Ord}$ is a successor cardinal and $\theta$ regular, but the converse needn't hold.  By reflection there are plenty of $\gamma <(\theta ^+)^L$ where $L_{\gamma}$ thinks $\mathrm{Ord}$ has successor length; and if $\theta$ is singular in $L$, a subset of $\theta$ witnessing this need not show up immediately at stage $L_{\theta +1}$.

Comment: Bah!  I started writing that comment before you posted yours but didn't finish til after, so just ignore it!  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. There are some nice ideas in that paper. In the matter of fragments of PFA, you may also want to look at the recent paper by Neeman and Schimmerling. 